# EACCESS err while installing thin

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, ruby

I am trying to install thin in linux mint 17. I have installed ruby via rvm . I have already install the thin gem. When I ran `thin install` I got this error

```
    Installing thin service at /etc/init.d/thin ...
mkdir -p /etc/init.d
writing /etc/init.d/thin
/home/sushant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/controllers/service.rb:41:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /etc/init.d/thin (Errno::EACCES)
    from /home/sushant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/controllers/service.rb:41:in `open'
    from /home/sushant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/controllers/service.rb:41:in `install'
    from /home/sushant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/runner.rb:200:in `run_command'
    from /home/sushant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/thin-1.6.4/lib/thin/runner.rb:156:in `run!'
    from /home/sushant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/thin-1.6.4/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/sushant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/thin:23:in `load'
    from /home/sushant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/sushant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/sushant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I know that this is related with permission. When I googled, I found out that I should not use sudo if I am using RVM. Plus I am not sure if I should chmod it to 777.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possibilities.

1. Install a Ruby via the system package if you haven't already. (It might already be there) Having done that, then `sudo su -` and use that ruby without rvm. I don't think generally as root you want to be running rvm except in very special cases which I don't think is what you have here.
2. Look at the mode permissions on /etc/init, change it to something that works as your user (e.g. 775 or 777). Then change it back after install.